# How to switch to Anaconda environment in VS code without adding Anaconda to system PATH

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I tried to use the Anaconda environment in Visual studio code and I have selected the conda environment as the interpreter.
[image]
But when I click "Run Python File in Terminal" the command "conda activate base" is run first.

```
PS C:path\to\workspace> conda activate base
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,     
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ conda activate base
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Yet I haven't added the Anaconda environment to system PATH since the official website says it might cause problems.

So I'm wondering is there a way to use conda environment without adding it to the system path? I know that I can start vscode in the Anaconda Prompt by using `code path/to/workspace`. But then I can't switch to other interpreters inside vscode.

Comment: Be careful not to use the `base` environment for development, it can lead to a bunch of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Can you find this file?

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

If not, you can try to init it with the command of:

```
conda init powershell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to set the system PATH you can use settings.json for vscode

```json
{
  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\Users\<username>\Anaconda3\envs\<env name>\bin\python.exe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the Anaconda Powershell app as a custom terminal profile with the following steps (Running Windows 11)...

1. Locate **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** in file browser > Right click and select **properties** > Copy contents of the **Target** field e.g.

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\<user>\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\<user>\miniconda3' "
```

2. Remove the path to powershell.exe and format the satement as a string that can be passed to VS Code settings (note the use of backslash as an escape character) e.g.

```
" powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command \"& 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\Users\\<user>\miniconda3' \" "
```

3. Create a new terminal profile in **settings.json** and add the string to the **args** section (commmas are used to spread the string over multiple lines).

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": 
    // Other profiles...
    "Anaconda":{
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args":[
            "powershell.exe",
            "-ExecutionPolicy",
            " ByPass",
            "-NoExit",
            "-Command",
            "\"& 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\Users\\<user>\\miniconda3' \""
        ]
    }
}
```

You can now choose to use this profile when you need to access conda, or you can set it as your default profile for the workspace. If you set this as your default profile, conda should work as expected after choosing your python interpreter. Hope this helps!